# Hbase error while executing ./bin/start-hbase.sh (windows)

Tags: java, windows, hadoop, hbase

I installed Hadoop with this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g7Qpnmi0Q-s and it´s working. I installed it in C:/hadoop.

I installed it only because I read that hadoop is a prerequisite for executing (no single mode) and the error messages are regarding some hadoop configurations. But it didn´t help.

I tried to install Hbase with this tutorial https://ics.upjs.sk/~novotnyr/blog/334/setting-up-hbase-on-windows. But I´m getting this error while executing `./bin/start-hbase.sh`

Output in cygwin terminal:

```
$ ./bin/start-hbase.sh
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further detail
s.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further detail
s.
: Name or service not knownstname laptop-l6543teb
running master, logging to /cygdrive/c/java/hbase-2.2.4-bin/hbase-2.2.4//logs/hbase-maiwa-master-LAPTOP-L6543TEB.out
: running regionserver, logging to /cygdrive/c/java/hbase-2.2.4-bin/hbase-2.2.4//logs/hbase-maiwa-regionserver-LAPTOP-L6543TEB.out
```

hbase-site-xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>file:///C:/cygwin/root/tmp/hbase/data</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
        <value>C:\Java\hbase-2.2.4-bin\hbase-2.2.4\logs</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Environment variables:

[image]

Path variables:
[image]

Comment: Did you setup the required Environment Variables while installing hadoop?

Comment: @franklinsijo Yes I did it. Please have a look above. I added screenshots of my variables.

Comment: update the `HADOOP_HOME` to `"C:\hadoop\"` and add one more environment variable `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` with value `"C:\hadoop\etc\hadoop\"`

Comment: @franklinsijo I updated the output of the console above in the question. Please check again. I´m facing SLF4J errors

Comment: I have updated the answer to handle the errors in your hbase installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error output produced by `start-hbase.sh` has three different errors.

**1.** Issue with `HADOOP_HOME` variable

```
WARNING: DEFAULT_LIBEXEC_DIR ignored. It has been replaced by HADOOP_DEFAULT_LIBEXEC_DIR. WARNING: log4j.properties is not found. HADOOP_CONF_DIR may be incomplete. 
ERROR: Invalid HADOOP_COMMON_HOME
```

Update the Environment variables with `HADOOP_HOME` pointing to the Hadoop installation folder (not the `bin` folder within the installation folder).

As per your setting,

```
HADOOP_HOME=C:\hadoop\
```

Additionally, set the location of the configuration files

```
HADOOP_CONF_DIR=C:\hadoop\etc\hadoop\
```

**2.** Issue with interpreting Linux style path or Invalid path

```
cygpath: can't convert empty path
```

In `hbase-env.sh` (under `C:\Java\hbase-2.2.4-bin\hbase-2.2.4\conf\`), update the values for `HBASE_HOME` and `HBASE_CLASSPATH`

As per your installation,

```
export HBASE_HOME=/cygdrive/c/Java/hbase-2.2.4-bin/hbase-2.2.4/
export HBASE_CLASSPATH=/cygdrive/c/Java/hbase-2.2.4-bin/hbase-2.2.4/lib/
```

And in your environment variables, make sure `HBASE_HOME` is configured similar to `HADOOP_HOME`.

**3.** Unable to resolve hostname

```
: Name or service not knownstname laptop-l6543teb
```

Update your `hosts` file with correct IP - Hostname mapping.

Comment: The first error regarding hadoop home is solved. But the other two ones are still there with the new changes. I don´t understand the third error. my hostname is laptop-l6543teb. I tried it also with the value of my IPv4 Address. But still the same error....

Comment: Do you still get `cygpath: can't convert empty path` when running `start-hbase.sh`?

Comment: Is the path I have mentioned for `HBASE_HOME` correct? Also, could you update the question with the `hbase-site.xml`?

Comment: Is the `cygpath` issue resolved? And in your `hbase-site.xml`, there is an additional entry for `hbase.rootdir` with `hdfs` path, that can be removed.

Comment: No it´s still not resolved. Okay I removed it. I updated the question with the current environment variables and current output. Please check

Comment: If you remove the old error messages from your post, this answer won't make any sense for someone else looking for same issue in the future. Please add your changes as subsequent updates leaving the original question unchanged.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211636/discussion-between-maiwand-and-franklinsijo).